dotnet not recognized in visual studio 2022
I'm trying to use .NET within Visual Studio 2022, but I keep getting the following error:

dotnet : The term 'dotnet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.

However, when I run dotnet --version in the command prompt, it works fine.
When I try the same command in the Package Manager Console within Visual Studio 2022, I get the error mentioned above.
Here’s what I’ve checked and tried so far:

The system PATH is set correctly.
.NET is listed as installed in Programs and Features.
I repaired Visual Studio 2022, but it didn’t fix the issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Is it vs2022 or VS studio code? you mentioned both. So it's working in the cmd but not PowerShell? Do you have the .Net SDK installed?
Maybe take a look at https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5379

What does use dotnet within VS studio code mean? What you posted looks like a Powershell error. VS Code doesn't install the .NET SDK or runtime. Visual Studio does only if you select the appropriate .NET workload


First check if you have dotnet installed at all. Start cmd or Terminal/Powershell and type: dotnet --help. Then you can get two outcomes: dotnet is installed (then go to step 2) or dotnet is not installed (or it may seem not to be - go to step 2)
If you are sure that dotnet is installed, then ensure that "C:\Program Files\dotnet" is part of the "path" system environment variable.
If nothing helps, you could try repairing Visual C++ Redistributable


"However, when I run dotnet --version in the command prompt, it works fine" gives the answer to the first question...

Did you check the PATH variable? There must be: C:\Program Files\dotnet

Regarding the problem that the dotnet command can be used in the command prompt, but an error occurs in the Package Manager Console in VS, please refer to the following suggestions:
1: Go to this link to reinstall the .NET SDK, and then restart the computer.
2: Make sure PATH points to the installation location (usually in C:\Program Files\dotnet).
3: If it still doesn't work, you can try running the command in View > Terminal to see if the problem still occurs.
In addition, here are related posts similar to this problem for reference: post1, post2
